# How to create a Stomp Websocket Client in .NET that uses HTTP?

Tags: c#, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I built a Websocket Server in Java with [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

My server configuration looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/my-websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
```

I've created a client in Javascript which works, and the connection looks like:

```
function connect() {
    var myUsername = document.getElementById('from').value;
    var host = 'http://localhost:8080/my-websocket';
    var socket = new SockJS(host);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        stompClient.send('/app/status', {}, JSON.stringify(createUserStatus('AVAILABLE')));
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/status', function (message) {
            receiveStatus(JSON.parse(message.body));
        });
        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/private.message.' + myUsername, function (message) {
            displayMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
        });
    });
}
```

Now I want to create a client in .NET, but every Stomp client library I've found, doesn't allow `http` to be the URI, and my server only accepts `http` connections. My server fails to parse `ws` and `tcp` connections, and I can't find a client out there that uses `http`.

In my .NET client, when I try to connect to `string brokerUri = "tcp://localhost:8080/my-websocket"`

My server throws this exception:

```
client-id:ID:DESKTOP-AA29FJ6-52716-637205011942817986-0:0
host:localhost
accept-version:1.0,1.1
heart-beat:10000,30000

 ]
2020-03-22 19:13:14.414 DEBUG 25036 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

How can I create a Websocket connection in .NET that can subscribe to different topics and queues, and send messages over `http`?

Alternatively, how could I make my server handle `ws` or `tcp` connections?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [spyBiz](https://github.com/sypbiz/SockJS.NET). They implement SockJS implementation using C#. SockJS framework is using `http` or `https` for calling the websocket server instead of `ws` or `tcp`